# rror: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 84 of the expression

Tags: angularjs

I get below error on the code:

```
ng-class='{removeActiveStyle:!(item.one || item.day || item.time)
          ,showToolTip:!(item.one || item.day || item.time)}'
```

**Error stack**

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 84 of the expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the exact same condition. You can write it like this :

```
ng-class="{'removeActiveStyle showToolTip': !(item.one || item.day || item.time)}"
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r69vq0ef/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose class name between single quotes,Plus you should also go through ngClass documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
ng-class="{'removeActiveStyle':!(item.one || item.day || item.time)
          ,'showToolTip':!(item.one || item.day || item.time)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The others beat me too it!

But they are all right, you require quotes around your classes.

```
<div ng-class="{
                   'condition1':     (item.one && item.two && !item.three),
                   'condition2':     !(item.one || item.two || item.three),
                   'condition3':     (item.one || item.two || item.three)
                }">
    This is a test div
</div>
```

Heres a working fiddle with 3 conditions and some applications of the styles

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zzakdr0/4/)